# ExactTarget -- SMS/ POST/message/optin

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm trying to create a sms opt-in message through rest UI.

Below is the JSON request I formed

{
    "messageName":"TESTMESSAGE1234",
    "shortCode":"86288",
    "countryCode":"US",
    "keyword":"JA",
    "messageOptInType":"Single",
    "responseMessage":"Hey thanks!",
    "allowSingleOptIn":"true",
    "duplicateOptInMessage":"You already subscribed to receive our messages",
    "optinErrorMessage":"An error occured. Please try again."
}

I'm posting the above JSON request to URL, https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/message/optin in POST method.

I'm getting the following error response,

{
  "message" : "Validation Error",
  "errorcode" : 10006,
  "documentation" : "",
  "validationErrors" : [
    {
      "message" : "Cannot save message because another message overlaps with it on this keyword.",
      "errorcode" : 10000,
      "documentation" : ""
    }
  ]
}

. Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you don't have an active SMS Opt-in message already active with the same keyword JA?  Might be best to remove the Keyword all together.